# jquery change() on input box in IE6 - can't remove focus

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, focus, onchange

I have a checkout page that unobtrusively checks to see whether a customer has ordered from us before.

After they fill in their e-mail address and focus to the next box, I look up the e-mail and present a 'welcome back' type thing with option to remember their details.

I'm getting a problem in IE6 - whenever the focus is lost from the input box, the ajax function runs as normal but focus is returned back to the input box. This means that whenever the customer tries to click away from the e-mail input box, they keep getting returned to it and cannot proceed.

Is there a way of stopping this behaviour?

```
  // check when the e-mail box is changed
  $("#email").change(function(event) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "procBasketEmailLookup.php", 
        data: $("#checkoutform").serialize(),
        success: function(response) {
            $('#emailstuffOutput').hide();
            $('#emailstuffOutput').html(response);
            $('#emailstuffOutput').show('slow');
        }
        });
        // DON'T ALLOW THE PAGE TO SUBMIT
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: What happens if you don't return "false" from the script?

Comment: @Pointy Then the form will submit and redirect to the action page.

Comment: @vivin Why would the form be submitted if you remove "return false"?

Comment: @Mattias

Argh, my bad - I thought he was using `submit()`. Disregard what I said earlier.

Comment: Ahh, I see :) Because I think if he removes that it will work (not sure about this). And I can't see a reason for having it there.

Comment: Ohh, good point - that's probably why it keeps focus - because he keeps returning `false` from the `change()` handler.

Comment: Removed return false and it's working fine. I think I had copied it over from some other functions on the same page which would submit and forgot to remove it.

Thanks!

Comment: @vivi Yes, that was my thought as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
jQuery("#emailInputField").blur();
```

Put that in the success handler of your AJAX call, or even in your `change()` handler. I can't tell from your question if it's the AJAX call that's causing the problem, or if it's the `change()` handler. But this *should* work.

**EDIT**

With regard to Pointy's comment. Using `blur()` messes up the tab sequence. Also, Pointy and Mattias pointed out that you're returning `false` from your handler. There's no need for you to do that since you're not in a `submit()` handler. The `return false;` might also be the cause of your problem.

Comment: The problem with calling "blur()" is that it can mess up the "tab sequence".  If the user made a change and then used "tab" to go to the next field, calling "blur()" can cause the browser to reset the focus to some more-or-less random spot on the page.

Comment: Good point; I'm updating the answer anyway - it looks like it might be related to the `false` that he's returning from the `change()` handler.